# Swipe on listView with tabs

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, swipe, gesture

Here goes the scenario:

I have this activity with two tabs, each tab one fragment, in one of these fragments I have an [Header ListView](http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/), and I want to hack it and got each line with an event of swipe (left or right), then I tried this:

```
private void setUpCardListView(View v){
        HeaderListView list = (HeaderListView) v.findViewById(R.id.hlv_card_items);

    list.setAdapter(new SectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d(LogUtils.LOGTAG, "ASAS");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }

...
```

this code is called `onCreateView` of my fragment, and when I try to swipe one item of my list view I didn't get any log.

Here goes my SectionAdapter:

```
public abstract class SectionAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnItemClickListener, RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private int mCount = -1;

public abstract int numberOfSections();

public abstract int numberOfRows(int section);

public abstract View getRowView(int section, int row, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);

public abstract Object getRowItem(int section, int row);

public boolean hasSectionHeaderView(int section) {
    return false;
}

public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return null;
}

public Object getSectionHeaderItem(int section) {
    return null;
}

public int getRowViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

public int getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

public int getSectionHeaderItemViewType(int section) {
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Must return a value between 0 and getRowViewTypeCount() (excluded)
 */
public int getRowItemViewType(int section, int row) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
/**
 * Dispatched to call onRowItemClick
 */
public final void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    onRowItemClick(parent, view, getSection(position), getRowInSection(position), id);
}

public void onRowItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int section, int row, long id) {

}

@Override
/**
 * Counts the amount of cells = headers + rows
 */
public final int getCount() {
    if (mCount < 0) {
        mCount = numberOfCellsBeforeSection(numberOfSections());
    }
    return mCount;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return getCount() == 0;
}

@Override
/**
 * Dispatched to call getRowItem or getSectionHeaderItem
 */
public final Object getItem(int position) {
    int section = getSection(position);
    if (isSectionHeader(position)) {
        if (hasSectionHeaderView(section)) {
            return getSectionHeaderItem(section);
        }
        return null;
    }
    return getRowItem(section, getRowInSection(position));
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
/**
 * Dispatched to call getRowView or getSectionHeaderView
 */
public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int section = getSection(position);
    if (isSectionHeader(position)) {
        if (hasSectionHeaderView(section)) {
            return getSectionHeaderView(section, convertView, parent);
        }
        return null;
    }
    return getRowView(section, getRowInSection(position), convertView, parent);
}

/**
 * Returns the section number of the indicated cell
 */
public int getSection(int position) {
    int section = 0;
    int cellCounter = 0;
    while (cellCounter <= position && section <= numberOfSections()) {
        cellCounter += numberOfCellsInSection(section);
        section++;
    }
    return section - 1;
}

/**
 * Returns the row index of the indicated cell Should not be call with
 * positions directing to section headers
 */
public int getRowInSection(int position) {
    int section = getSection(position);
    int row = position - numberOfCellsBeforeSection(section);
    if (hasSectionHeaderView(section)) {
        return row - 1;
    } else {
        return row;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if the cell at this index is a section header
 */
public boolean isSectionHeader(int position) {
    int section = getSection(position);
    return hasSectionHeaderView(section) && numberOfCellsBeforeSection(section) == position;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of cells (= headers + rows) before the indicated
 * section
 */
public int numberOfCellsBeforeSection(int section) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(numberOfSections(), section); i++) {
        count += numberOfCellsInSection(i);
    }
    return count;
}

private int numberOfCellsInSection(int section) {
    return numberOfRows(section) + (hasSectionHeaderView(section) ? 1 : 0);
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    mCount = numberOfCellsBeforeSection(numberOfSections());
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
    mCount = numberOfCellsBeforeSection(numberOfSections());
    super.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}

@Override
/**
 * Dispatched to call getRowItemViewType or getSectionHeaderItemViewType
 */
public final int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int section = getSection(position);
    if (isSectionHeader(position)) {
        return getRowViewTypeCount() + getSectionHeaderItemViewType(section);
    } else {
        return getRowItemViewType(section, getRowInSection(position));
    }
}

@Override
/**
 * Dispatched to call getRowViewTypeCount and getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount
 */
public final int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getRowViewTypeCount() + getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount();
}

@Override
/**
 * By default, disables section headers
 */
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return (disableHeaders() || !isSectionHeader(position)) && isRowEnabled(getSection(position), getRowInSection(position));
}

public boolean disableHeaders() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isRowEnabled(int section, int row) {
    return true;
}
```

}

I think the TouchEvent is going to change my tab, instead of swiping my listItem. Am I right? How can I fix this issue?

Thanks folks!

Comment: don't use swiping tabs, that would help